# Polaroid Image Gallery with only css

Tags: css

**UPDATE**

here is a js-fiddle with images available: http://jsfiddle.net/TBwWw/

I am using a tutorial that I found [here](http://zurb.com/article/305/easily-turn-your-images-into-polaroids-wi).

I have an unordered list that simply links the image to a larger one and also displays the image on the page.

```
<ul class="polaroids"> 
   <li>
      <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/zurbinc/3971679981/" title="Roeland!">
        <img src="example/cyan_hawk.jpg" alt="Roeland!">
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And then css that is supposed to be adjusting the image size, add the polaroid effect and a whole lot more.

```
ul.polaroids a:after {
content: attr(title);
}

/* By default, we tilt all our images -2 degrees */
ul.polaroids a {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    transform: rotate(-2deg);
}

/* Rotate all even images 2 degrees */
ul.polaroids li:nth-child(even) a {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(2deg);
    transform: rotate(2deg);
}
/* Don't rotate every third image, but offset its position */
ul.polaroids li:nth-child(3n) a {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -o-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    transform: none;
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}

/* Rotate every fifth image by 5 degrees and offset it */
ul.polaroids li:nth-child(5n) a {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
    transform: rotate(5deg);
    position: relative;
    right: 5px;
}

/* Keep default rotate for every eighth, but offset it */
ul.polaroids li:nth-child(8n) a {
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;
    right: 5px;
}

/* Keep default rotate for every eleventh, but offset it */
ul.polaroids li:nth-child(11n) a {
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
    left: -5px;
}

/* Scale the images on hover, add transitions for smoothing things out, and ensure the hover appears on top */
ul.polaroids a:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.25);
    -o-transform: scale(1.25);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
    transform: scale(1.25);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}

/* Add drop shadows and smooth out the transition (Safari only) */
ul.polaroids a {
    -webkit-transition: 0 .15s linear;
    -moz-transition: 0 .15s linear;
    -o-transition: 0 .15s linear;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}

/* On hover, darken the shadows a bit */
ul.polaroids a {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

The end result is supposed to be:

[image]

But they are just appearing with just the unordered list text decoration and the after title effects like so:

[image]

Everyone else in the comments on the tutorial said it worked just fine. I don't understand why it isn't working for me. I do have the css in an external style sheet that is linked and being found correctly. Finally, the Google Chrome console is showing no errors. I have tried it in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Comment: Didn't even cross my mind to make one. Jsfiddle coming up!

Comment: Here's one with different images since the original code had local paths. Same Markup and CSS though... http://jsfiddle.net/DrydenLong/jC84f/

Comment: I don't see anything in your code removing the list style and I don't see anything that would make the text wrap down below the image.

Comment: You need to make some ammendments DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/TBwWw/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jC84f/1/

```
ul.polaroids { width: 970px; margin: 0 0 18px -30px; }
ul.polaroids li { display: inline; }
ul.polaroids a { background: #fff; display: inline; float: left; margin: 0 0 27px 30px; width: auto; padding: 10px 10px 15px; text-align: center; font-family: "Marker Felt", sans-serif; text-decoration: none; color: #333; font-size: 18px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25); -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25); -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg); -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .15s linear; -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg); }
ul.polaroids img { display: block; width: 190px; margin-bottom: 12px; }
ul.polaroids a:after { content: attr(title); }

ul.polaroids li:nth-child(even) a { -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);  -moz-transform: rotate(2deg); }
ul.polaroids li:nth-child(3n) a { -webkit-transform: none; position: relative; top: -5px;  -moz-transform: none; }
ul.polaroids li:nth-child(5n) a { -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); position: relative; right: 5px;  -moz-transform: rotate(5deg); }
ul.polaroids li:nth-child(8n) a { position: relative; right: 5px; top: 8px; }
ul.polaroids li:nth-child(11n) a { position: relative; left: -5px; top: 3px; }

ul.polaroids li.messy a { margin-top: -375px; margin-left: 160px; -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg); -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg); }

ul.polaroids li a:hover { -webkit-transform: scale(1.25); -moz-transform: scale(1.25); -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5); -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5); position: relative; z-index: 5; }

code { background: rgba(0,0,0,.5); padding: 2px 3px; color: #fff; text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.75); -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; }

ol.code { background: rgba(0,0,0,.75); margin-bottom: 18px; border: solid rgba(0,0,0,.75); border-width: 1px 1px 0; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5); }
ol.code li, ol.code li code { font-size: 14px !important; }
ol.code code { background: none; }
```

Comment: Literally, all I did, was look at the code they were using by using Google's Inspect Element.  I don't know why they didn't post the correct code in their article, but this is the code that's on the page in the demo http://zurb.com/playground/css3-polaroids

Comment: I tried using: http://www.dirtymarkup.com/ before posting and it had me add quite a bit of code. (the code I posted is after changing it with them) But still didn't change, Suppose I should have used Google's instead! Didn't know they had one.

Comment: @user2371301 In Chrome, just right click the element (in this case the `li`) and it will pull up the Elements tab in the console.  Then, you can see what styles it is using.

Answer (score 0):

First off, all the images are supposed to be in a single `ul`, not separate ones as you have in your fiddle. Second, you're missing the list styles, and `display`/`float` properties to make things wrap.

I was able to get your example to wrap by adding the following CSS:

```
ul { list-style: none; }
ul li { display: inline; }
ul a {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
ul img { display: block; }
```

I think this is essentially what you're missing, so you'll probably want to adjust things to how you like (including spacing, classes, etc.). Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jC84f/3/